# Why can't I complete the Rangfust puzzle in the Time Machine level?

Tags: the-cave

In the "Time Machine" level, I reach a point in the level where I am supposed to:

> Move a boulder in the past, to create a well in the present.

I have watched videos which show how to do this, and yet I can't do it myself.  For reference I am currently playing with the Scientist, Twins, and Time Traveler.  It seems like when I switch between characters my character in the past may be dying (as in the "poof" that occurs when the environment kills them), but I can't see how.  I am also playing on XBox 360 if that helps.

Comment: When you move the boulder, are you still holding onto it when you change to your character in the present? By that, I mean are you still holding the grab button as you're switching?

Comment: That did the trick @Fluttershy.  Make that an answer and I will accept.  I don't know how I was supposed to know that pressing the "hold" button was essential - but whatever, at least it is solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, the game is a tad buggy at times. In order to ensure the boulder stays out of the way for your character in the present, you need to continue holding the grab button as you switch to your other character. This will ensure your character doesn't just let go of the boulder.